# Turn off opera mouse gesture hints

Tags: windows-7, opera

In the latest opera there's a big black circle that appears whenever i hold down the right mouse button. I know how to use gestures and the hint is freaking distracting. Any way to turn it off?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this:

```
opera:config#UserPrefs|ShowGestureUI
```

into your address bar and untick the option. Done

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to Menu / Settings / Preferences, Advanced tab, Shortcuts, and then create your mouse setup and turn on any mouse gestures you don't use? I've done that and I don't get the circle you're describing.